# How do I pass arguments to makecontext()'s start routine?

Tags: c, ucontext

I'd like to pass 3 arguments to `thread_routine_handler` like this:

```
makecontext(&th->context, thread_routine_handler, 3, th, start_routine, arg);
```

but I don't know how to read them properly. It returns the warning:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘makecontext’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-type void (*)(thread_t *, void (*)(), void *) {aka void (*)(struct thread *, void (*)(), void *)}
```

my callback routine is defined like this:

```
void thread_routine_handler(thread_t *th, start_routine_t start_routine, void *arg_routine)
{ ... }
```

It's working but I'm afraid of some UB behavior. The 2 argument of makecontext does expect a function taking no arguments. How am I supposed to read them? even with va_start() etc I do need at least one argument (argc) or am I missing something? what's the proper way to do that?

**UPDATE**

start_routine_t is `typedef void (*start_routine_t)();`

Comment: What's a `start_routine_t`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger typedef void (*start_routine_t)(); I'll also add to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected type for the second parameter to `makecontext()` is `void (*)()`.  As the diagnostic message indicates, the type of the argument you are passing is `void (*)(thread_t *, void (*)(), void *)`.  These are not "compatible" types in the sense in which the C language spec uses that term, on account of the latter being declared with a function prototype and the former not.

However, given the particular types of the parameters to your `thread_routine_handler()` function, it is possible to call that via a pointer of type `void (*)()`, provided that the actual arguments are of the correct types.  <s>The best available solution is to apply an appropriate typecast to the `makecontext()` argument.  If the actual arguments are not of exactly the correct types, then you should cast those, too.  Thus, in full generailty:</s>

```
makecontext(&th->context, (void (*)()) thread_routine_handler,
        3, (thread_t *) th, (start_routine_t) start_routine, (void *) arg);
```

You can omit any of those casts that convert values to (exactly) the types they already have.

**But that's largely irrelevant here**, because you have an issue with the *other* arguments that your compiler is not diagnosing (understandably).  The variable arguments to `makecontext()`, those that are forwarded to the specified function, are required to all be of type `int` (thanks, @user253751). Their number can vary, but not their types.  I overlooked that in the original version of this answer.

It follows that `thread_routine_handler()` can accept any number of arguments compatible with type `int` or `unsigned int`, but none of any other type.  You will still need to cast the pointer to the start function, as already described, but you cannot safely use the particular function you are trying to use.  Possibly you can set up a global, dynamically-allocated table of the `th`, `start_routine`, and `arg` triples, and pass an index into that.

Comment: this is safe, i.e. not will not cause undefined behavior or something like that, right?

Comment: The `makecontext` function specifically expects `int` arguments. What makes it safe to pass argument types other than `int`? I am aware that on most ABIs they are probably passed the same way.

Comment: My apologies, @Jack -- I have had to make a major modification to this answer after your acceptance.  The whole sense of it has changed.

Comment: Damn, @user253751, that's a good question.  Answer revised.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see... Can I do something like void thread_routine_handler(int a, int b, intc c) then do something like `thread_t *th = (thread_t *) a;` etc?

Comment: No, @Jack, it is not safe to rely on conveying pointers by converting them to type `int`.  It might *happen* to work on machines where `int` and all pointer types, including function pointers, have the same size, but there are lots of machines where that is not the case.  Most 64-bit machines, for example, and, historically, most machines with 16-bit `int`s.

Comment: @JohnBollinger any other way to pass pointer to this function without using globals?

Comment: @JohnBollinger so void thread_routine_handler(int index) { } calling them like     makecontext(&th->context, (start_routine_t) thread_routine_handler, 1, myIndex); is the way to go then, right?

Comment: That's what I recommend, @Jack.  In principle, you can encode arbitrary information, including pointer values, into a long enough sequence of integers (and probably two per pointer would be enough here), but that's ugly and error prone.  If you use "globals" with internal linkage (*i.e.*, declare them `static` at file scope) and therefore use them only in functions defined in the same file, then I don't think you need to be too put off.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i see, i'll use a global with static then. thanks!